# Which metrics should I use to scale a microservice application integrated with Prometheus and Kubernetes?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot application which is running in a Kubernete cluster successfully. But now I want to scale the application when we receive more traffic. So what are the metrics that I should consider if I am using Prometheus/Grafana combination in my application? The prometheus gives me lots of metrics, but I am a bit confused about which one should I use for HPA (Horizontal Pod scaling).

Comment: The answer for this question depends on a type of your app. Is it simple http web server or some kind of "proxy"? Or is it some complex, resource consuming, CPU/RAM extensive processes involved in background?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using cpu or memory usage. say, if the usage goes above 80% scale the pods

sample based on cpu utilization

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: php-apache
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: php-apache
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you should install the metric server https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server before creating HPA